# How to generate custom triples with OpenIEDemo.java provided by stanford-nlp

Tags: java, python, nlp, stanford-nlp

I have trained custom NER and Relation extraction model and I have checked generating triples with corenlp server but when I'm using [OpenIEDemo.java](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/naturalli/OpenIEDemo.java)
to generate triples it's generating triples having relations "has" and "have" only but not the relations on which I have trained my Relation Extraction model on.

I'm loading custom NER and Relation Extraction model while running the same script. Here is my OpenIEDemo.java file...

```
package edu.stanford.nlp.naturalli;

import edu.stanford.nlp.ie.util.RelationTriple;
import edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.Annotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP;
import edu.stanford.nlp.semgraph.SemanticGraph;
import edu.stanford.nlp.semgraph.SemanticGraphCoreAnnotations;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.CoreMap;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.PropertiesUtils;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;

/**
 * A demo illustrating how to call the OpenIE system programmatically.
 * You can call this code with:
 *
 * <pre>
 *   java -mx1g -cp stanford-openie.jar:stanford-openie-models.jar edu.stanford.nlp.naturalli.OpenIEDemo
 * </pre>
 *
 */
public class OpenIEDemo {

  private OpenIEDemo() {} // static main

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, depparse, natlog, openie");
    props.setProperty("ner.model", "./ner/ner-model.ser.gz");
    props.setProperty("sup.relation.model", "./relation_extractor/relation_model_pipeline.ser.ser");
    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);

    // Annotate an example document.
    String text;
    if (args.length > 0) {
      text = args[0];
    } else {
      text = "Obama was born in Hawaii. He is our president.";
    }
    Annotation doc = new Annotation(text);
    pipeline.annotate(doc);

    // Loop over sentences in the document
    int sentNo = 0;
    for (CoreMap sentence : doc.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class)) {
      System.out.println("Sentence #" + ++sentNo + ": " + sentence.get(CoreAnnotations.TextAnnotation.class));

      // Print SemanticGraph
      System.out.println(sentence.get(SemanticGraphCoreAnnotations.EnhancedDependenciesAnnotation.class).toString(SemanticGraph.OutputFormat.LIST));

      // Get the OpenIE triples for the sentence
      Collection<RelationTriple> triples = sentence.get(NaturalLogicAnnotations.RelationTriplesAnnotation.class);

      // Print the triples
      for (RelationTriple triple : triples) {
        System.out.println(triple.confidence + "\t" +
            triple.subjectLemmaGloss() + "\t" +
            triple.relationLemmaGloss() + "\t" +
            triple.objectLemmaGloss());
      }

      // Alternately, to only run e.g., the clause splitter:
      List<SentenceFragment> clauses = new OpenIE(props).clausesInSentence(sentence);
      for (SentenceFragment clause : clauses) {
        System.out.println(clause.parseTree.toString(SemanticGraph.OutputFormat.LIST));
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As OpenIE module of stanfordCoreNLP not using custom relation model(don't know why) I can not use custom relation extraction model with this code instead I had to run SanfordCoreNLP pipeline adding path for my custom NER and Relation Extraction model in server.properties file and generate triples. If someone know the reason why OpenIE is not using custom Relation Extraction model please comment, it will be very useful for others.